Why do I get a "Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception" when using the Swiss Ephemeris library?
I'm trying to use library Swiss Ephemeris.
I have downloaded the dll "swedll64.dll" from GitHub: https://github.com/aloistr/swisseph in "contrib/swedll64_2.02.01.zip"
I have use "dependency walker" for see the functions, I have all the functions, but I can only use swe_julday and swe_calc, for the others I have this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Attempt to call undefined C function 'swe_pheno'

But "swe_pheno" is in the functions listed in my dependency walker.
For example this works:
    <?php
include("define/define.php");

// FFI
$ffi = FFI::cdef("
    void swe_set_ephe_path(const char *path);
    int swe_calc(double tjd, int ipl, int iflag, double *xx, char *serr);
    double swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour, int gregflag);
", "C:\sweph\swedll64.dll");  // Remplacez par le chemin correct

// Définir le chemin où se trouvent les fichiers d'éphémérides
$ephe_path = "C:\sweph\swissEphe";
$ffi->swe_set_ephe_path($ephe_path);

// Date et heure pour calculer le jour julien
$year = 1992;
$month = 6;
$day = 3;
$hour = 1.0;
$gregflag = 1;  // 1 pour calendrier grégorien
$tjd = $ffi->swe_julday($year, $month, $day, $hour, $gregflag);

// Calculer la position d'une planète (par exemple, le Soleil)
$ipl = SE_SUN;  // Planète
$iflag = 2;  // 2 = Calcul avec précision (SEFLG_SWIEPH)

$xx = FFI::new("double[6]");
$serr = FFI::new("char[256]");

//$ret = $ffi->swe_calc($tjd, $ipl, $iflag, $xx, $serr);

//if ($ret < 0) {
//    echo "Erreur : " . FFI::string($serr);
//} else {

    // Afficher la position en signe
    $sign_names = ["Bélier", "Taureau", "Gémeaux", "Cancer", "Lion", "Vierge", "Balance", "Scorpion", "Sagittaire", "Capricorne", "Verseau", "Poissons"];
    foreach ($planets_list as $planet) {

        // Appel de la fonction
        $ret = $ffi->swe_calc($tjd, $planet, $iflag, $xx, $serr);

        // Calculer les degrés en signe
        $longitude = $xx[0];
        $sign = intval($longitude / 30); 
        $deg_in_sign = $longitude - ($sign * 30);  // Degré dans le signe

        // Résultat renvoyé
        echo "Le ".$planet_name[$planet]." est à " . $deg_in_sign . "° " . $sign_names[$sign] ."<br>". "\n";
    }

But not this (error uncaught as seen above):
$ffi = FFI::cdef("
    void swe_set_ephe_path(const char *path);
    int swe_calc(double tjd, int ipl, int iflag, double *xx, char *serr);
    double swe_julday(int year, int month, int day, double hour, int gregflag);
", "C:\sweph\swedll64.dll"); 

// Définir le chemin où se trouvent les fichiers d'éphémérides
$ephe_path = "C:\sweph\swissEphe";
$ffi->swe_set_ephe_path($ephe_path);

// Date et heure pour calculer le jour julien
$year = 1992;
$month = 6;
$day = 3;
$hour = 1.0;
$gregflag = 1;  // 1 pour calendrier grégorien

$tjd = $ffi->swe_julday($year, $month, $day, $hour, 1);

// Récupérer les phases de la Lune
$attr = FFI::new("double[20]");
$serr = FFI::new("char[256]");

$ffi->swe_pheno($tjd, 1, 0, $attr, $serr); // 1 pour la Lune


Look at what you pass to FFI::cdef(). Anything not in there is not accessible to you.
